# Heroku deployment error "required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be found."

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, jwt

I am trying to deploy my springboot app to heroku but I am getting an error that it cannot find a JwtDecoder bean. I have tried googling it a bit but can't find anything that helps. Everything works fine locally, just not when deployed to heroku.

Here is my heroku log --tail:

```
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134160+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************************
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134160+00:00 app[web.1]: APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134160+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************************
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134161+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134161+00:00 app[web.1]: Description:
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134161+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134179+00:00 app[web.1]: Method springSecurityFilterChain in
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration 
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that 
could not be found.
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134179+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134179+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134180+00:00 app[web.1]: Action:
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134180+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-27T20:18:45.134181+00:00 app[web.1]: Consider defining a bean of type 
'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' in your configuration.
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
```

I'm not sure what else to include... Feel free to comment on what else I should add. Or, the repo is at https://github.com/AndreTheTallGuy/Kelp2

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot find `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder` because you listed that dependency as `test scope`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Change the `scope` or just remove that entry. Default entry is `compile`.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I already have spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client and spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server in the dependency list. Adding spring-security-test didn't help. Any inputs?

Answer (score 18):

Try to specify the **jwk-set-uri** configuration in application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

For application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

```
@SpringBootTest(
        properties = {
                "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri = http://<host>:<port>/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"}
)
```

example with keycloak

Answer (score 1):

use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt")` in your main application class.

Answer (score 1):

Add the JwtDecoder @Bean like so, and check if it works

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation("your-issuer-uri");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
```